# Add operators to make the equation correct

Tags: mathematics

I am trying to solve this puzzle:

> Add operators(and brackets if necessary) to make the following equation correct: $3$ $3$ $7$ $7$ $=24$. You may also rearrange the numbers if necessary.

Despite trying hard, I could not figure this out. The fact that rearranging the numbers was allowed somehow made this harder for me. Any help in this problem is appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is:

> $$(3 + 3\div 7) \times 7 = 24$$